# Xamarin PCLStorage Access denied when trying to read folder created in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using PCLStorage v1.0.2 in Xamarin Forms v2.3.4.247.

When I create a folder and save files to it, I can access them perfectly within my app.

However, when I create a folder from the Android Device Monitor and add files to the folder, I cannot access the files.

I get this error:
`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files/MyApp/Samples' is denied.`

I have properly set access to read/write external storage (again, I can create/read from within my app).

I also have proper R/W privileges:

The dir/files in YELLOW were created/saved within my app and are accessible.

The dir/files in GREEN were created/saved from the Android Device Monitor and are NOT accessible.

[image]

If anything, I have MORE privileges with the green files, yet I still get an error.....

Here's the relevant - it is THE SAME when I access each folder (except, of course the folder name)

```
private static PCLStorage.IFolder objDir;
objDir = await App.rootDir.GetFolderAsync("Samples");
IList<IFile> picList = await objDir.GetFilesAsync(); //error occurs here for green files....
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: When you use Android Device Monitor create file, you could try to put your file in '/data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files/` folder.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT  I am putting them there - you can see the path in my post inside the Error....

Comment: I mean put files in `/data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files/` folder, instead of putting them in your `Samples` folder, I test it and works fine, you could try it.

Comment: I see what you mean - but will that stop me from using sub-directories? Also, it doesn't explain why files added from my app work but files added from my pc don't work...

Comment: For now I didnt find the reason, once I find it I will come back to tell you.